# 403 Forbidden Error for Videos on a production serve

Tags: php, laravel, video

I am trying to access videos in a for loop from the storage in my Laravel app, however, I am getting a 403 error. This only happens on my production site, I can load them locally and I tested it on a dev site and they load fine. I know that they are there on the server and if I hard code them in the videos will load just fine. I also have other images on the same page that are loading just fine from the server. So I am kind of at a loss as to why they won't load or are forbidden. In my controller I have it like this:

```php
public function showNewItem(Request $request, $id)
{
    $products = Product::all();
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
    $prod_images = Product::find($id)->images;
    $prod_videos = Product::find($id)->videos;
    
    return view('pages.whats_new', compact('product', 'prod_images', 'prod_videos'))->withProducts($products);
}
```

And in my view I have this as my loop:

```php
@foreach($prod_videos as $video)
    <div class="video--container__item">
        <video controls width="100%" height="auto" src=" /storage/product_video/{{ $video->video }}">        
         </video>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

A little further down the page, I load the product images in the exact same way, they load with no error:

```php
@foreach($prod_images as $image)
    <div class="image grid-item">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
            <a href="{{ asset("storage/product_image/{$image->product_image}") }}">
                <img src="{{ asset("storage/product_image/{$image->product_image}") }}" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
            <div class="img-overlay">
            <h3 aria-hidden="true">
                {{ $image->image_title }}
            </h3>
            <p aria-hidden="true">
                {{ $image->caption }}
            </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

I have never encountered this before. Is it something in the code? I cannot figure it out. I have tried to rewrite this code using eager loading but then all the images are the same across each product page and videos just don't show up at all in locally, in development or in production.

Here is the Screen shot of the error I am seeing:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a CORS error? You should have a look at the console logs.

Comment: I am not really sure, I have never had to deal with that so I am not sure what I would be looking for.

Comment: so it seems like with CORS the console would log that it is a CORS error. Is that correct? The error that I get just says 403 Forbidden.

Comment: Maybe I can be of more help if you share the Console screen.

Comment: I have added a screenshot to the bottom of my question for refrence.